# vfscanf.c warning: the scanf functions add several kilobytes of bloat

Tags: c, linux, warnings

I received this warning message while using dietlibc. Is it due to the dietlibc version. I'm using diet 0.33

I'm unable to resolve this warning kindly help me out

Comment: If you don't care about a few extra kb then just ignore the warning.

Comment: First: Do you know what the warning means? Second: Do you know the purpose of dietlibc?

Comment: I'm working out on bringing up the board and in the process for finding a smaller sized library I came across dietlibc. I posted this query of mine as I am unable to figure out the cause of this warning. So please if you have the solution kindly share it with me, else there are lots of people who can solve your query regarding the purpose of dietlibc and what the warning means!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your program requires the scanf library functions to be added to your object code. This is either because you use sscanf or some other such function, or maybe you call a function that in its turn requires the scanf functions.

The scanf (and printf) libraries are famous for being huge. They require all the functions that decode (and encode) strings and hexadecimal and floating point, etc. etc. You can end up with a 2k program expanded to 20k just because you use a single scanf function.

The warning is telling you that your program may be taking up more space than it otherwise would because you have required the scanf library to be used.

**Edit:**

A library is a collection of object files. The linker adds whichever object files are necessary to your program. It cannot include part of an object file; it's all or nothing. Because vscanf is included in libstdio.o in dietlib, any stdio function that you use will pull in vsscanf.

See https://github.com/hchunhui/dietlibc/blob/master/Makefile :

```
LIBSTDIOOBJ=$(patsubst libstdio/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(wildcard libstdio/*.c))

DIETLIBC_OBJ = $(OBJDIR)/unified.o \
$(SYSCALLOBJ) $(LIBOBJ) $(LIBSTDIOOBJ) $(LIBUGLYOBJ) \
$(LIBCRUFTOBJ) $(LIBCRYPTOBJ) $(LIBSHELLOBJ) $(LIBREGEXOBJ) \
$(OBJDIR)/__longjmp.o $(OBJDIR)/setjmp.o \

$(OBJDIR)/dietlibc.a: $(DIETLIBC_OBJ) $(OBJDIR)/start.o
    $(CROSS)ar cru $@ $(DIETLIBC_OBJ)
```

And note that vsscanf is in the libstdio directory.

Personally I would have tried to put the scanf and printf functions in a separate object file because they are so big. I've also seen some libraries that ship with two versions of scanf and printf, one of which doesn't support floating point just to keep code size down. However there may be a good reason for doing it the way they've done it.

The only way to avoid pulling in all of stdio would be not to use any of it -- use the file descriptor functions (open rather than fopen, read rather than getc).

Comment: I get that my scanf library function is not added. I traced back the linking warning generated by fflush call  . But the problem still remains

Comment: I see that the fflush library also warns about taking over 7k of space, but it doesn't seem to require scanf.

Comment: I've just looked at the dietlib source-code. vsscanf is part of the libstdio.o object module. That means that if you use any stdio functions then you will also get scanf included. That's not necessarily how I would have done it myself but that's what happens. The only way to avoid it would be not to use any stdio stuff. A library is a collection of object files. The linker adds whichever object files are necessary to your program. Because vscanf is included in libstdio.o in dietlib, any stdio function that you use will pull in vsscanf.

Comment: is this due to static linking of the dietlibc because dynamic linking is not permitted in dietlibc

Comment: By the comment you made earlier about "bringing up the board" I assumed you were programming an embedded computer. Dynamic linking is often, or even usually, not avaliable then. I'm no expert at dietlib -- this is the first time I've come across it -- the readme only mentions static linking, but that makefile seems to also create a dynamic library.

Comment: But if you are memory-limited then dynamic or static, you need memory to hold the libraries. A shared library just means the library can be shared between several programs. If you are only running one program that uses the library then you will get little advantage by using dynamic linking and it may even use more memory. In fact in this case it may even load every object module into memory, even the ones that you are not using. So in this case, dynamic libraries are probably not a solution.